# Apache needed for NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, apache, webserver

On my local machine I have set up a web project like toled in a tutorial.
I have installed XAMPP and used MySQL and Apache to run my Node.JS backend.
Now I'm about to use a external server to host the project and make it available through the internet.

So I have to setup the server and I want to know why I need Apache (from XAMPP) to run the Node.JS backend? I thought the node.js is a web server by itself?
So would it be a clever idea to set up the external server again with XAMPP?

When I want to start index.html by the URL could I also do this with the node.js?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No you won't need an Apache server. Because Node itself will serve as a Server Especially if you are working with Frameworks like Express.

We can use Nginx if we want. It's very cosy to some people use Nginx to do the load balance, or even other stuff like handle the https or server static content. It's your choice at the end.

For best performance, though, you'll combine node.js with nginx, depending on the needs of your application.  nginx does a better job of serving static files, though at the highest performance for static files will come from using a CDN.  Most often, you'll use nginx as a reverse proxy: the web request will be received by nginx, which acts as a load balancer in front of several identical or subdivided servers.  If it needs to server static files as well, it will just answer those requests directly.

Comment: The project is just for a some employee, so I think there are not many people using the webapp at the same time (>10). The backend is using some google services so there could be a couple requests/response operations. Do you think nginx is also needed for this? I haven't worked with nginx till yet

Comment: No, you won't need Nginx server at all. Your normal Node server can easily handle around 500 Users on **Microserver** instance.

Comment: Yes, Even if you start Node project in normal pc it can easily handle more than 50 users.You can go without Nginx or Apache you won't face any issues even if users will increase.

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily need Apache to run Node.js since they both accomplish the same thing - answer HTTP requests.

However, they are scenarios where you might use them together. For instance, you might use [Apache as a `reverse-proxy`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html)to Node.js back-end server. Or even use Node.js as the reverse proxy to Apache.

Comment: Such a scenario is when you wan't to listen port 80 in Node.js, but it is already used by Apache, since you have other projects that need Apache, like PHP websites, in this case, you can use Apache as a proxy server, and Node.js listens another port.